# Maven cant find relative path

Tags: java, path, relative-path

My problem is that the path just works when it's in the project but when i try to run it in the .jar that i created doesnt seem to work

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    ReadPath("clock/src/main/resources/Csv/Path.txt");
    ReadCsv("clock/src/main/resources/Csv/MondayA.csv");
    ReadCsvL("clock/src/main/resources/Csv/MondayL.csv");
    SetTime();

}
```

[This is how it looks the directories in the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdhAd.png)

Comment: what's the source code for ReadPath and ReadCsv and readCsvL files?

Comment: It seems that the project name is `cloak`, right? Please check if the name of `.jar` file is same with it. OTOH, I don't think it is proper to include project name in its path literal. Use `getClass().getResuource()` or such like that.

Comment: @codingmonster i tried using that but since the ReadCsv and ReadPath requires a string variable what should i do?
        ReadPath(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Csv/Path.txt"));
        ReadCsv(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Csv/MondayA.csv"));
        ReadCsvL(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Csv/MondayL.csv"));

Comment: When inside a jar, the classpath resources  don’t exist in the file system anymoreso you cannot use files

Comment: Did you check with `getClass().getResouce().getPath()`?

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: What is the result of `getClass().getResouce().getPath("/Csv/MondayA.csv")`? IMO, you should remove first `/`, such as `"Csv/MondaA.csv"` or `"./Csv/MondaA.csv"`

Comment: The result is C:/Users/User/Desktop/Proyectos/FenixClock/clock/target/classes/Csv/Path.txt

Comment: I see, `getClass()` would return the class that is on runtime so that the path is `.../target`. As the result, what about this - `../../Csv/Path.txt`?

Comment: is still not working and it returns C:/Users/User/Desktop/Proyectos/FenixClock/clock/target/classes/Csv/Path.txt

Comment: Then, please try this - `getClassLoader().getResource("Csv/Pah.txt").getPath()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect. You are using **relative** paths which are relative to your project path. And when you create the `jar` file, it will not be able to find them since the files that you are searching for are **in the jar file itself**.

The correct way to do this is:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    ReadPath(this.getClass().getResource("/Csv/Path.txt").toString());
    ReadCsv(this.getClass().getResource("/Csv/MondayA.csv").toString());
    ReadCsvL(this.getClass().getResource("/Csv/MondayL.csv").toString());
    SetTime();
}
```

Now the paths are the jar paths & the files are read from the `resources` folder which is located inside the jar.

------------ EDIT -------------

Most likely your `resources` folder, is not marked as the directory folder. From your Screenshot, I can see that you are using VS code (bad idea when coding with java). There are a lot of IDEs that make your life simpler and save you headaches as the one that you have.

I also see a `pom` file, which means you are using maven.

Following this [these instructions](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html), this is how you mark the directory through maven:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

**Or try moving your resources folder IN `src/main`**.

Comment: It's still not finding the path what im doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using VS code as your code editor?